# reparing user list on a linux system using cfengine

Tags: linux, uac, configuration-management, cfengine

I need to create a cfengine policy which automatically maintains a user list on a linux box. If there are additional users on the system except the list, it would delete them. I am a newbie to cfengine. Any pointers would be immensely appreciated. Also let me know if i am trying to solve the problem in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [`users:` promise type](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/master/reference-promise-types-users.html) in CFEngine 3.6.0 to manage local user accounts.

You can use the [`getusers()` function](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.5/reference-functions-getusers.html) to get a list of all the users on the system, and then [iterate](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.5/manuals-language-concepts-loops.html) through it to determine which users need to be added or deleted.

Hope this helps you get started.